# SUM of a column from a second degree join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to query 3 tables: `students`, `template_subjects`, and `subjects`.

The `students` and `template_subjects` tables have a `template_code` column, so I can join them through this column (which I think is a pivot table between a `template_codes` table and the `subjects` table. This isn't a database I designed, just querying it now).

Now, I need to get the sum of the `units` column from the `subjects` table grouped by the `template_code`. How can I do it?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT 
s.studNo as 'Student Number',
s.lastName as 'Student Name',
s.template_code as 'Template Code',
(SELECT sum(units) FROM subjects
JOIN template_subjects ON subjects.subject_code=template_subjects.subject_code
GROUP BY s.template_code) as 'Units'
FROM students as s
JOIN template_subjects ON template_subjects.template_code=s.template_code
```

What I expect to get from the query is, for example:

```
Student Number | Student Name | Template Code | Units
201555101        Jane Doe       ACC301          35
```

Where `Units` is the total units of subjects inside a certain template code. (Table names and columns have much more complex names, so I simplified them in this question. Please inform me of any errors or confusing parts that I may have written in this question.)

Comment: You've got Student Number = Student Number and Student Name = 201555101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs the answer, here is how I made it work:

```
SELECT 
s.studNo as 'Student Number',
s.lastName as 'Student Name',
s.template_code as 'Template Code',
(SELECT sum(units) 
FROM template_subjects
JOIN subjects ON template_subjects.subject_code=subjects.subject_code
WHERE template_subjects.templade_code=s.template_code) as 'Units'
FROM students as s
JOIN template_subjects ON template_subjects.template_code=s.template_code
```

Please note this difference in the subquery:

```
WHERE template_subjects.templade_code=s.template_code
```

instead of:

```
GROUP BY s.template_code
```

And also, instead of querying the `subjects` table itself in the subquery, I queried the `template_subjects` instead and joined the `subjects` table.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT s.studNo as `Student Number`, s.lastName as `Student Name`,
       s.template_code as `Template Code`,
       (SELECT sum(ts.units)
        FROM template_subjects ts  
        WHERE s.subject_code = ts.subject_code
       ) as Units
FROM students s;
```

That is, you just need a correlated subquery and not quite so many joins.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. `template_subjects` doesn't have a units column, it's on the `subjects` table. So I can connect the student to the template_subject, and the template_subject to the subjects based on a subject_code.